# ¿Cómo evitar que me rediriga de pagina al presionar boton eliminar?

Tags: javascript

Estoy añadiendo nuevas funciones a un proyecto entregado, el tema que debo hacer verificación y estoy implementando SweetAlert2, el tema es que tengo problemas ya que en un tr pusieron que lo redirigiera a la vista detallada, por lo que cada vez que pincho en el boton eliminar, me abre el sweetalert2 y me redirige inmediato a al vista detalles sin poder hacer la confirmacion para eliminar.

```
<table class="table table-listbox table-bordered_ table-responsive-md table-striped_ text-center_"
                      id="laravel_crud" style="">
  <tbody>
    @foreach($opportunities as $opportunity)
     <tr data-id="{{$opportunity->id}}" data-route="{{ route('opportunity.show',$opportunity->id)}}"
                          style="cursor:pointer">
      <td width="20">
        @if($opportunity->user)
        <canvas title="{{ $opportunity->user->name }}" class="user-icon" width="24"
          height="24"></canvas>
        @endif
      </td>
      <td>{{ $opportunity->name }}</td>
      <td>{{ $opportunity->account ? $opportunity->account->name : '' }}</td>
      @endif
      @can('delete opportunity')
      <td> 
        <a class="btn iq-bg-danger btn-rounded btn-sm eliminar" href="">Eliminar</a>
        <button type="button" class="btn iq-bg-danger btn-rounded btn-sm eliminar">Eliminar</button>
        @endcan
     
    </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Aqui dejo el script, la importación de la libreria funciona, esta puesta en el archivo NPM del proyecto, cuando presiono eliminar, me presenta el mensaje de confirmación pero al estar el ONCLICK ne el TR no me deja hacer mucho ya que me lleva a otra pagina y no me deja realizar la acción de eliminarlo.

```
<script>
  //Agrega onclick a TR
  $('table tr').click(function(e) {
    // Evitar redirigir si es un botón eliminar
    if(!$(e.currentTarget).hasClass('eliminar')) {
      // No es botón, redirigir tomando el atributo desde data-route
      window.location.href = $(e.currentTarget).data('route');
    }
  });

  //Elimina solo los que tienen clase "Eliminar"
  $('table .eliminar').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Obtener ID desde TR
    let id = $(this).closest('tr').data('id');
    
    Swal.fire({
      title: "¿Estás seguro?",
      text: "de eliminar la oportundiad",
      icon: "warning",
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
      cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
      confirmButtonText: 'Si, eliminar!',
      cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar',
      reverseButtons: true
    }).then((result) => {
      if (result.value) {
      //eliminarUser(id);
      }
    })
  });

  function eliminarUser(id){
    var urlGlobal = "{{url('/')}}";
    var urlDestroyUser = urlGlobal+"/users/"+id;
    var token = '{{csrf_token()}}';
    var data = {id:id,_token:token};
  
    $.ajax({
      type: 'DELETE',
      url: urlDestroyUser,
      data: data,
    success: function (response){
      Swal.fire({
        title: "Eliminación exitosa!",
        icon: "success"
      })
      .then((result) => {
        if (result) {
          location.reload();
        }
      })
    },
    error: function(response){
      Swal.fire(
        'Error',
        'Ha ocurrido un problema',
        'error'
        )
      }
  })
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Veo un foreach y dentro la generación de etiquetas con un ID constante (`<a id="eliminar"...`). Huele a problema

Comment: Si el tema que ya el foreach es de la tabla que lista, el tema que al pasar el mouse sobre la fila, esta se superponga y puedas presioanr en cualquier lado para que te rediriga a la vista de de detalle, eso esta funcional ya que lo hizo otro programador. 
El tema va

Comment: Edita la pregunta para agregar el código que usas para mostrar _sweetAlert_ para ver si podemos ayudarte a quitar el _onclick_ del TR y agregarlo en función aparte.

Comment: @Triby listo aqui actualize y agregue el script. La priemra parte de ocnfirmar o cancelar se muetsra pero desaparece rapido por culpa del listener onclick que me redirige altiro.

Comment: tambien veo que el ultimo td no esta cerrado

Comment: @JackNavaRow si si eso ya lo arregle de colocarle el ultimo TD depsues de que habia publicado esto 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como te mencionaron en comentarios, los ID deben ser únicos para evitar problemas, entonces cambia el atributo e inclúyelo como clase del botón "Eliminar".

Otro problema que tenías, era que no estabas guardando ID del elemento y no había forma de conseguirlo al hacer clic. La propuesta es:

- Elimina el evento *onclick* de cada TR
- Agrega en TR dos atributos de datos, uno para ID del elemento y otro para la ruta a donde debe redirigir

```
             <table class="table table-listbox table-bordered_ table-responsive-md table-striped_ text-center_"
                  id="laravel_crud" style="">

                  <tbody>
                    @foreach($opportunities as $opportunity)
                    <tr data-id="{{$opportunity->id}}" data-route="{{ route('opportunity.show',$opportunity->id)}}"
                      style="cursor:pointer">
                      <td width="20">
                        @if($opportunity->user)
                        <canvas title="{{ $opportunity->user->name }}" class="user-icon" width="24"
                          height="24"></canvas>
                        @endif
                      </td>
                      <td>{{ $opportunity->name }}</td>
                      <td>{{ $opportunity->account ? $opportunity->account->name : '' }}</td>
                      @endif
                      @can('delete opportunity')
                      <td> 
                        <a class="btn iq-bg-danger btn-rounded btn-sm eliminar" href="">Eliminar</a>
                        <!--<button class="btn iq-bg-danger btn-rounded btn-sm my-0" type="submit">Eliminar</button>-->
                      </td>
                      @endcan
                     
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
                  </tbody>

                </table>
```

Luego, en Javascript:

- Creas una función para escuchar clic en TR
- Si el clic no proviene de un botón, entonces rediriges
- De lo contrario, no realizas acción, esa la va a capturar el botón
- La función para escuchar clic en botón se lanza por clase y no por ID
- Tomas ID del elemento a eliminar desde el atributo *data-id* del TR
- Muestras la alerta y, en caso de confirmar, ejecutas la función enviando ID
- En la función, ejecutas la petición AJAX y, en vez de recargar la página con `location.reload()`, solo eliminas la fila correspondiente

```
<script>
  // Agregar onclick a TR
  $('table tr').click(function(e) {
    // Evitar redirigir si es un botón eliminar
    if(!$(e.target).hasClass('eliminar')) {
        // No es botón, redirigir tomando el atributo desde data-route
        window.location.href = $(e.currentTarget).data('route');
    }
  });
  
  // Solo los enlaces con clase "eliminar"
  $('table .eliminar').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Obtener ID desde TR
    let id = $(this).closest('tr').data('id');

    Swal.fire({
    title: "¿Estás seguro?",
    text: "de eliminar la oportundiad",
    icon: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: 'Si, eliminar!',
    cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar',
    reverseButtons: true
    }).then((result) => {
      if (result.value) {
        eliminarUser(id);
      }
    })
  });

  function eliminarUser(id){
    
    var urlDestroyUser = '{{$opportunity.delete}}';
    var token = '{{csrf_token()}}';
    var data = {id:id,_token:token};
  
    $.ajax({
      type: 'DELETE',
      url: urlDestroyUser,
      data: data,
    success: function (response){
      Swal.fire({
        title: "Eliminación exitosa!",
        icon: "success"
      })
      .then((result) => {
        if (result) {
          // En lugar de recargar
          // location.reload();
          // Elimina solo la fila
          $(`[data-id="${id}"]`).remove();
        }
      })
    },
    error: function(response){
      Swal.fire(
        'Error',
        'Ha ocurrido un problema',
        'error'
        )
      }
  })
  }
</script>
```

**Importante:** El único problema al eliminar la fila directamente, podría ser que el *token* caduque y sí se requiera recargar o buscar la forma de obtener uno nuevo; de hecho, esto último sería lo ideal para tener buena funcionalidad de la página.

Tal vez puedas crear una variable global para almacenar el *token* original y, después de eliminar un registro, borrar la fila y actualizar la variable.

```js
// Agregar onclick a TR
  $('table tr').click(function(e) {
    // Verificar dónde si hizo el clic
    console.log($(e.target).hasClass('eliminar'));
    // Evitar redirigir si es un botón eliminar
    if(!$(e.target).hasClass('eliminar')) {
        // No es botón, redirigir tomando el atributo desde data-route
        console.log($(e.currentTarget).data('route'));
    }
  });

  $('table .eliminar').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      // Obtener ID desde TR
      let id = $(this).closest('tr').data('id');
      console.log(id);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-listbox table-bordered_ table-responsive-md table-striped_ text-center_" id="laravel_crud" style="">
    <tbody>
    <tr data-id="1" data-route="{{ route('opportunity.show',1)}}"
                      style="cursor:pointer">
        <td width="20">
        </td>
        <td>Nombre 1</td>
        <td>Nombre de cuenta 1</td>
        <td> 
           <a class="btn iq-bg-danger btn-rounded btn-sm eliminar" href="">Eliminar</a>
          <!--<button class="btn iq-bg-danger btn-rounded btn-sm my-0" type="submit">Eliminar</button>-->
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-id="2" data-route="{{ route('opportunity.show',2)}}"
                      style="cursor:pointer">
        <td width="20">
        </td>
        <td>Nombre 2</td>
        <td>Nombre de cuenta 2</td>
        <td> 
           <a class="btn iq-bg-danger btn-rounded btn-sm eliminar" href="">Eliminar</a>
          <!--<button class="btn iq-bg-danger btn-rounded btn-sm my-0" type="submit">Eliminar</button>-->
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Pero solo reconoceria por el tipo de clase si redirigir a otra pagina o no? ya que lo he implementado como dices y funciona bien pero el problema que confirmar la eliminación sigue desapareciendo a los 3 segundos y me auto redirige al detalle. Cambie el *a* por un button type="button", lo mantuve como a y seguia redirigiendo. Igual gracias y muy buena la explicación no soy experto y aun estoy en un modo junior de aprendizaje con js y jquery y lo de eliminar la fila me va a servir muchisimo.

Comment: @AlexValenzuela, no debería redirigir, a menos que no hayas quitado el _onclick_ del TR o no hayas agregado la clase al botón.

Comment: E si quite del TR el onclick, le agregue los data-id y data-route en el TR.  Le agregue la clase eliminar al <a class="btn iq-bg-danger btn-rounded btn-sm eliminar" href="#">Eliminar</a><button type="button" class="btn iq-bg-danger btn-rounded btn-sm eliminar">Eliminar</button> Lo probe con el A HREF y con el BUTTON, pero llega y presenta la alerta y rapidamente me redirige a otra pagina con el id, es extraño.

Comment: @AlexValenzuela, edita la pregunta para poner el código actualizado, a ver si encontramos el error.

Comment: Listo, solo había que cambiar `.currentTarget` en: `if(!$(e.target).hasClass('eliminar'))`. Agregué un fragmento de código al final de la respuesta para probar que funciona.

Comment: Hay lo actualize, gracias igual ahora si primera vez que veo eso de current target y target, voy a tener que buscar un buen curso de js para aprender a manejarlo bien ya que pueod decir que se lo mas basico de eso. muchas gracias :D

Comment: @AlexValenzuela, no te preocupes, nunca vas a dejar de aprender. No suelo usar jQuery y por eso es que no puse mucha atención en la diferencia entre _.target_ y _.currentTarget_, este último hace referencia al elemento con el que creas la función, mientras que _.target_ al elemento real que disparó el evento.